# Customer Can Comment at Checkout Step

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

How can I put the comment box like "Order_Comment" at checkout step for the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a FREE ready-made exrtension for this : [Magemaven OrderComment](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magemaven-ordercomment.html)

Also if you want to create an Exrtension yourself, follow this complete tutorial : [Order Comment at Checkout](http://www.appseconnect.com/how-to-add-order-comment-on-customer-checkout-in-magento/)